# Ability for users to print or export embedded PowerBI report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm really new to PowerBI.
I have a report embedded on a webpage for other non-PowerBI users (clients).
I want to know if there is a way that the clients will be able to either print the report or to send it as an email attachment from the webpage. Can either of these be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow your consumers to print the report. This can be easily achieved by using Power BI JavaScript APIs.

First add an HTML button, which will allow the user to click to Print their report.

```
<button id="theClick" onclick="print()">Print</button>
```

Once you have your button, then add the javascript for it.

```
function print() {
            var element = $('#report-container')[0];
            var report = powerbi.get(element);

            report.print();

        }
```

For more information, you can read the official documentation by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embedding-basic-interactions.

You can use Power Automate to export your reports via email. The official documentation link is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export